# Process builder, Invalid field 'CreatedDate' for object 'dlrs__LookupRollupSummary__c' Class

Tags: process-builder, soap-api

I created a process builder in order to automate the creation of events in a public calendar when a user creates an opportunity. We have presentation date for the opportunities and we wanted to have then as events in the calendar
I created the flow that is working great, but from the moment I activated it I am getting EVERY HOUR a ton of email notification on errors, I do not even understand.

Could you please help me to figure out how to solve it, please?

Here is the error:

> Error element myRule_6_A1 (FlowRecordCreate).
> This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: dlrs_EventTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.InvalidFieldException: Invalid field 'CreatedDate' for object 'dlrs__LookupRollupSummary__c' Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.getFieldPath: line 91, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.addOrdering: line 543, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.configureQueryFactory: line 434, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 318, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 300, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector.CustomObjectSelector: line 165, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector: line 80, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 1135, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 816, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler: line 311, column 1 Trigger.dlrs_EventTrigger: line 7, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: dlrs_EventTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.InvalidFieldException: Invalid field 'CreatedDate' for object 'dlrs__LookupRollupSummary__c' Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.getFieldPath: line 91, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.addOrdering: line 543, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.configureQueryFactory: line 434, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 318, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 300, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector.CustomObjectSelector: line 165, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector: line 80, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 1135, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 816, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler: line 311, column 1 Trigger.dlrs_EventTrigger: line 7, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: dlrs_EventTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.InvalidFieldException: Invalid field 'CreatedDate' for object 'dlrs__LookupRollupSummary__c' Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.getFieldPath: line 91, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.addOrdering: line 543, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.configureQueryFactory: line 434, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 318, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 300, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector.CustomObjectSelector: line 165, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector: line 80, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 1135, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 816, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler: line 311, column 1 Trigger.dlrs_EventTrigger: line 7, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: dlrs_EventTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.InvalidFieldException: Invalid field 'CreatedDate' for object 'dlrs__LookupRollupSummary__c' Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.getFieldPath: line 91, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.addOrdering: line 543, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.configureQueryFactory: line 434, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 318, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 300, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector.CustomObjectSelector: line 165, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector: line 80, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 1135, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 816, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler: line 311, column 1 Trigger.dlrs_EventTrigger: line 7, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: dlrs_EventTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.InvalidFieldException: Invalid field 'CreatedDate' for object 'dlrs__LookupRollupSummary__c' Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.getFieldPath: line 91, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.addOrdering: line 543, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.configureQueryFactory: line 434, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 318, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 300, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector.CustomObjectSelector: line 165, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector: line 80, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 1135, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 816, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler: line 311, column 1 Trigger.dlrs_EventTrigger: line 7, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: dlrs_EventTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.InvalidFieldException: Invalid field 'CreatedDate' for object 'dlrs__LookupRollupSummary__c' Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.getFieldPath: line 91, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.addOrdering: line 543, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.configureQueryFactory: line 434, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 318, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 300, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector.CustomObjectSelector: line 165, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector: line 80, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 1135, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 816, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler: line 311, column 1 Trigger.dlrs_EventTrigger: line 7, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: dlrs_EventTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.InvalidFieldException: Invalid field 'CreatedDate' for object 'dlrs__LookupRollupSummary__c' Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.getFieldPath: line 91, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.addOrdering: line 543, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.configureQueryFactory: line 434, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 318, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 300, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector.CustomObjectSelector: line 165, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector: line 80, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 1135, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 816, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler: line 311, column 1 Trigger.dlrs_EventTrigger: line 7, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: dlrs_EventTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.InvalidFieldException: Invalid field 'CreatedDate' for object 'dlrs__LookupRollupSummary__c' Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.getFieldPath: line 91, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.addOrdering: line 543, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.configureQueryFactory: line 434, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 318, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 300, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector.CustomObjectSelector: line 165, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector: line 80, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 1135, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 816, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler: line 311, column 1 Trigger.dlrs_EventTrigger: line 7, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: dlrs_EventTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.InvalidFieldException: Invalid field 'CreatedDate' for object 'dlrs__LookupRollupSummary__c' Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.getFieldPath: line 91, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.addOrdering: line 543, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.configureQueryFactory: line 434, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 318, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 300, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector.CustomObjectSelector: line 165, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector: line 80, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 1135, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 816, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler: line 311, column 1 Trigger.dlrs_EventTrigger: line 7, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: dlrs_EventTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.InvalidFieldException: Invalid field 'CreatedDate' for object 'dlrs__LookupRollupSummary__c' Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.getFieldPath: line 91, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.addOrdering: line 543, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.configureQueryFactory: line 434, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 318, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 300, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector.CustomObjectSelector: line 165, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector: line 80, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 1135, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 816, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler: line 311, column 1 Trigger.dlrs_EventTrigger: line 7, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: dlrs_EventTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.InvalidFieldException: Invalid field 'CreatedDate' for object 'dlrs__LookupRollupSummary__c' Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.getFieldPath: line 91, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_QueryFactory.addOrdering: line 543, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.configureQueryFactory: line 434, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 318, column 1 Class.dlrs.fflib_SObjectSelector.newQueryFactory: line 300, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector.CustomObjectSelector: line 165, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupSummariesSelector: line 80, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 1135, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService: line 816, column 1 Class.dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler: line 311, column 1 Trigger.dlrs_EventTrigger: line 7, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

Comment: If you have installed DLRS, you need to check the roll-up summary rules you have created. To check that you have to go Manage Roll Up summaries tab

Comment: I have it installed but I am not using the rollup anymore, when I saw the error I did the process not using the rollup but another work around.Could you be more specific please ? thx you ;)

Comment: After you have installed DLRS, you have created a trigger called 'dlrs_EventTrigger' which is throwing this exception. As you have mentioned you are not using the roll-up, , there are two ways to resolve it: 1. Go to Manage Lookup Rollup Summaries tab and check each rule under Select Lookup Rollup Summary. If anyone of those rule contains Event as either Parent or Child. Delete that. 2. Deactivate dlrs_EventTrigger

Comment: Thx you ! I checked all our rollup summaries under the tab manage but none of them have Event as Parents or child. How do I deactivate dlrs_EventTrigger?

Comment: Go to Setup => Event Trigger => Locate that Trigger => Click on Edit & Uncheck the Active checkbox